# What subcommentaries on Adi Shankaracharya’s Bhagavad Gita Bhashya are available online in English?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, translation-request

The oldest surviving commentary on the Bhagavad Gita is the Advaita philosopher Adi Shankaracharya’s Bhagavad Gita Bhashya.  Now the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ramanujacharya’s Bhagavad Gita Bhashya has several subcommentaries, most prominently Vedanta Desikan’s Tatparya Chandrika, which is available in English on sadagopan.org.  (It’s a series of PDF’s starting [here](https://www.sadagopan.org/pdfuploads/Gita%20Bhashyam%20-%20Chapter%2000%20-%20Tatparya%20Chandrika%20-%20Avatarikai.pdf).)

My question is, what subcommentaries on Adi Shankaracharya’s Bhagavad Gita Bhashya are available online in English?  Is a translation of Anandagiri’s Tika there online, for instance?

Note that I’m looking for translations of traditional Sanskrit subcommentaries, not modern books.

Comment: https://b-ok.asia/book/2090485/42de22?dsource=recommend and https://b-ok.asia/book/860920/546e01?regionChanged

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda That’s not what I’m looking for.  I’m looking for translations of traditional Sanskrit subcommentaries, like Anandagiri’s Tika on the Bhagavad Gita Bhashya.

Comment: There are Hindī translations of Ānandagiri ṭīkā but I don’t know of any Eng. translations of the same.