# does Gita has a sub commentary?

Tags: advaita, gita, commentary, shankara

I mean specifically a sub commentary on shankara bhasya

I have Google "Gita sub commentary" but the result refers to sridhara commentary not shankaras'

Comment: Duplicate: [What subcommentaries on Adi Shankaracharya’s Bhagavad Gita Bhashya are available online in English?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40737/what-subcommentaries-on-adi-shankaracharya-s-bhagavad-gita-bhashya-are-available)